# google-cloud-java get the current instance id and zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a java application which needs to know it's instance id.
How to do this with the google-cloud-java library?

In Go, it's pretty straight forward:

```
import metadata "cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata"

func main(){
    println(metadata.InstanceID))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I found it: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/969bbeef18f004fd51fd46c5def1ae5c644cae3c/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/MetadataConfig.java#L52

```
String instanceId = com.google.cloud.MetadataConfig.getInstanceId()
```